# How to properly cook a kid?

Tags: meat, goat

Goat. Goat kid.

I have a three month old goat kid that recently had to be moved to the freezer.

Most of the goat recipes that I see call for long braising in strong flavors. I assume they are using older animals with a lot of connective tissue and goaty flavor.

Is this true of kids as well? Can I just grill the meat like chicken or should I plan on doing a slow braise? Will this work for the rack of ribs as well as they seem to have more connective tissue?

I am going to be experimenting with this new meat but I want to waste as little as possible in my experiments.

Comment: I'm glad you specified @Sobachatina, otherwise I was going to call the cops!

Comment: This is the usual way here http://goo.gl/YWL5ZT. But you know, we aren't civilized people yet :)

Comment: Reminds me of home @belisarius :)

Comment: @belisarius- That actually does answer the question. Roasting directly over a fire is definitely not a braise and they are doing the entire animal. I don't have enough people to feed to roast it whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older goat tends to have a very strong flavor, hence why many suggest braising in strong flavors. You *can* braise your kid following these recipes - just remember to use 3/4th the amount of strong seasonings as you would for a regular goat.

As for grilling the meat, you could try to marinate the meat overnight with herbs and spices. Unlike chicken, which is a fairly blank canvas taste-wise, goat has a strong taste (even kid meat has a slight gamey/goat-y flavor). As I said, if grilling, marinate.

If you're braising or stewing, toss in a beer, some mint or basil and a few other herbs.

For the ribs - you could french them to get rid of some of the connective tissue and then marinate and roast them at low heat for a few hours to break down some of the connective tissue.

Good luck and great eating!

Comment: The kid did have a surprisingly strong goaty flavor. I marinated the meat overnight and grilled it the next day. It was delicious- firm but not tough. I am going to experiment with stronger spices next time.

Comment: Very glad it came out delicious. As a rule of thumb, always gauge the strength of the goaty flavor by the smell of the raw goat meat.